# How to pass model to a directive in Angular.js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to figure out how I could create a two-way binding between my directive and repeater. I have been trying all kinds of things I have found on the internet. This is what I have right now, but it doesn't pass item.myDate to the template where it would be needed.

How is this supposed to be done?

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">          
    <td>
        <mydirective dateModel="item.myDate"></mydirective>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**JS**

```
app.directive("mydirective", function(){
   return {
      restrict:'E',
      scope:{dateModel: "&"},
      template:'<input class="date" ng-model="{{dateModel}}">',
   };
});
```

Comment: you can add a controller to your directive, Put your data in the scope of that controller and that will be available as a model in your template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this changes.

1.

```
<mydirective date-model="item.myDate"></mydirective>
```

2.

```
app.directive("mydirective", function(){
   return {
      restrict:'E',
      scope:{dateModel: "="},
      template:'<input class="date" ng-model="dateModel">',
   };
});
```

Please refer [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jx7UTUHqea0cwvbPLSj0?p=preview)

Comment: That doesn't work either. I am not sure if that works just because it's not inside a repeater.

Comment: It seems to work inside a simple repeater: http://plnkr.co/edit/FMy25gGMEUUYvfn16DoD?p=preview I have to see my code what's breaking it.

Answer (score 1):

```
app.directive("mydirective", function(){
   return {
      restrict:'E',
      scope:{dateModel: '='},// Here you have to change in your code
      template:'<input class="date" ng-model="{{dateModel}}">',
   };
});
```

Comment: This also results in this error: Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{dateModel}}] starting at [{dateModel}}].

Comment: You want a value in ng-model or only name.  If name then remove "{{ }}" these brackets in template.

Comment: The value. As I stated in the initial question I need a two-way binding.

Answer (score 0):

change to this will work : scope:{dateModel: "="}.

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
app.directive("mydirective", function(){
   return {
      restrict:'E',
      scope:{dateModel: '@'},
      template:'<input class="date" ng-model="dateModel">',
   };
});
```

If you want your directive to use a different name (e.g. *myDate*) than the one used in your directive template, it should be something like this:

**HTML**

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in items">          
    <td>
        <mydirective myDate="item.myDate"></mydirective>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**JS**

```
app.directive("mydirective", function(){
   return {
      restrict:'E',
      scope:{dateModel: '@myDate'},
      template:'<input class="date" ng-model="dateModel">',
   };
});
```

Comment: This changed nothing. All I am getting is "Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{dateModel}}] starting at [{dateModel}}].

Comment: Right... remove the {{}} from the directive template. See here an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/2QSwUJj2ovtjSeseYBdS?p=preview

Comment: Still not working it just passes the string: "dateModel"

Comment: So you want two way binding, see the updated plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/2QSwUJj2ovtjSeseYBdS?p=preview If you're satisfied with the result, I'll edit my answer too

Answer (score 0):

Please go through  [this](http://jsfiddle.net/HarshMehta/6zf6ndtx/)  and one of the [good](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-sticky-notes-pt-2-isolated-scope/) read on same context. You will get clear idea on what you are missing currently.!! 
This is a good example showing you the difference

```
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <h2>Parent Scope</h2>
  <input ng-model="foo"> <i>// Update to see how parent scope interacts with  
   component scope</i>    
   <!-- attribute-foo binds to a DOM attribute which is always a string. 
     That is why we are wrapping it in curly braces so
     that it can be interpolated. -->
   <my-component attribute-foo="{{foo}}" binding-foo="foo"
    isolated-expression-foo="updateFoo(newFoo)" >
    <h2>Attribute</h2>
    <div>
        <strong>get:</strong> {{isolatedAttributeFoo}}
    </div>
    <div>
        <strong>set:</strong> <input ng-model="isolatedAttributeFoo">
        <i>// This does not update the parent scope.</i>
    </div>
    <h2>Binding</h2>
    <div>
        <strong>get:</strong> {{isolatedBindingFoo}}
    </div>
    <div>
        <strong>set:</strong> <input ng-model="isolatedBindingFoo">
        <i>// This does update the parent scope.</i>
    </div>
    <h2>Expression</h2>    
    <div>
        <input ng-model="isolatedFoo">
        <button class="btn" ng-click="isolatedExpressionFoo({newFoo:isolatedFoo})">Submit</button>
        <i>// And this calls a function on the parent scope.</i>
    </div>
  </my-component>
 </div>



  var myModule = angular.module('myModule', [])
  .directive('myComponent', function () {
    return {
        restrict:'E',
        scope:{
            /* NOTE: Normally I would set my attributes and bindings
            to be the same name but I wanted to delineate between
            parent and isolated scope. */                
            isolatedAttributeFoo:'@attributeFoo',
            isolatedBindingFoo:'=bindingFoo',
            isolatedExpressionFoo:'&'
        }        
    };
   })
   .controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.foo = 'Hello!';
    $scope.updateFoo = function (newFoo) {
        $scope.foo = newFoo;
    }
}]);
```